# Jquery method not working for button after html appended using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I load a html page with some html and javascript and the code is as followed

```
<button id="test"> test button </button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I have the script as followed (jquery is added properly)

```
<script>
$("#test").on("click" , function(){
    $("#result").text("hello world");
});
$("#button1").on("click" , function(){
        $("#result").text("goodbye world");
    });
</script>
```

The test button works fine. Now let's say instead of hello world 
being printed out we append the result div with an added button we have
a method already setup for.

```
<button id="test"> test button </button>
    <div id="result"><button id="button1">Button 1</button></div>
```

Nothing happens when button1 is clicked? Why is this exactly? I think it doesn't register the html since it was dynamically created. How can I make it so that something happens when this button is clicked? Thank you in advanced

Comment: Where's the method that adds the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this button is coming dynamically on page so you need to write its event like this:

```
$('#result').on("click","#button1" , function(){
            $("#result").text("goodbye world");
        });
```

or:

```
$(document).on("click","#button1" , function(){
        $("#result").text("goodbye world");
    });
```

Read more [**HERE**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: You need event delegation as suggested, https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Please don't use `document` as the delegation target if there's a better alternative.

Comment: @jack that element is coming dynamically after doam loaded whats the alternative instead of this??

Comment: What would a better alternative be Jack? body element?

Comment: The button is appended to `#result` which is there from the start; that should be the delegation target.

Comment: Thank you. So looking at this I need to reference it through $(document) otherwise it doesn't know where to look since the html was newly created?

Comment: yes you got it right.. when html is rendered on page after dom loaded we need to bind event using delegate which is this way i did

Comment: Except that you're using `document` as the delegation target whereas you should use `#result`.

Comment: @jack if i use #result are you sure event will fire??

Comment: It should, because there's already a `<div id="result">` on the page.

Comment: yes @Jack you are right now i understood your point. Thanks for the nice discussion

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").click(function () {
            $("#result").text("Hello");
        });
        $("#button1").click(function () {
            alert('');
            $("#result").text("hello world");
        });
    });
```